# dynamically add content to jsp site

Tags: jsp, asynchronous, queue

I am doing a query an a database and getting results from it. Those results may last for about 1 second each. I want to display these asynchronous on the HTML page in a table. What would be the most easy way to realize this? I already thought about some stuff like a queue, on that the API writes the results and a frontend reads them as far as they are written and publishes them in the table. So a kind of publisher - subscriber structrure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of approach, I would recommend DWR. It provides a mechanism to call server-side services from javascript, and rendering results in page using javascript as well.

http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

There are a lot of simple examples in this site.

Comment: Yes I have used DWR before and it works great. Make sure you use the latest version 3.  There are great examples on their site. 
Also, please make sure you pair up DWR with some good 'ol jquery to make your site dynamic.